# how can server send access token to client safely in google oauth2.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

I'm using google oauth2.0 code authorization flow in my app.
my app needs to use google api, so client side needs to set access_token as a Authorization header.
my app consists of two part. frontend is React built with create-react-app and backend api server is Koa.

Here is the flow

1. client get code and send back to server
2. server exchange code with access_token

the problem is, I have no idea how can api server send to client safely.

1. if server send access_token to post response body, it could be hijacked
2. if server send access_token within cookies with httpOnly, react app built with create-react-app  couldn't get access_token from cookie because it's CSR.

So I tried to build new jsonwebtoken with access_token and send to client within cookie with no httpOnly options.

I'm struggle into these.
how can server can send back to client some critical information safely?

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to react. however, the thing is for most deployed apps, you would use ssl, ie, an encrypted connection, ie, the https:// you see in most websites. here is how you can implement it in koa. it is perfectly fine to send accessTokens in headers.

[Add SSL to Node.js Koa Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689542/add-ssl-to-node-js-koa-server)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'll take a look